# Why are NS and SOA records not generated by AWS CloudFormer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I have managed to reverse engineer all of my Route 53 record sets into a CloudFormation template using the (beta) CloudFormer tool. However, for some reason my `NS` and `SOA` record sets are not present in the template — why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the values would be incorrect or not useful.

Route 53 populates these records with the correct values when a hosted zone is created.  Deleting that hosted zone and creating a new one (for the same domain) results in the assignment of new, different NS and SOA values.

Setting these records in the new hosted zone to match those of the old hosted zone will not accomplish anything other than making the new hosted zone's records be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I soon came to the same conclusion after using the CloudFormer-generated template to create a Route 53 stack.